# Redistributing ANTLR's Runtime classes

Tags: jar, licensing, runtime, antlr

I'm building a java project packaged as a jar file, which is partially based on ANTLR generated lexer/parser.
My question is, is it standard practice to redistribute ANTLR's runtime classes within the jar file, or if users need to obtain the ANTLR runtime on their own and ensure it is setup correctly on the classpath?

ANTLR's license (http://www.antlr.org/license.html) states the following:

"Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution."

However the runtime package doesn't seem to include a license file. Does this mean it's ok to re-distribute the binary, as long as the ANTLR license is added?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you're selling or otherwise distributing a packaged jar or executable, it's standard practice to include the ANTLR runtime.  You can include a README file in your distribution explaining that the ANTLR runtime is included and providing a copy of the license.

If you need to, the ANTLR license allows you to zip the ANTLR runtime classes in with your own classes, so that you can have a single executable jar file.